# Standard Java queue data structure with time qouta?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, queue

In order to implement service which limits of request count per time quantity I look for implementation of queue that reject adding elements if `enqueue()/add()` command exceeded some frequency rate?

So for example you can call `enqueue()/add()` no more that 1000 times per second and prevent high resource consuming service DDOS.

Also queue must reject `enqueue()/add()` if queue capacity were exceeded  (until you call `dequeue()/remove()`).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to reject with an Exception, or do you just want to ignore them.

A better approach might be to update a Map and ignore duplicate updates to a given key.  This drops events you couldn't process but ensuring the latest update of a key is always taken.

This way you consume N new message per second and can gracefully drop duplicates.

e.g.

```
final ConcurrentMap<String, Message> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10000);
int updateCount = 0;
long lastUpdate = 0;

public void enqueue(String key, Message message) {
    map.put(key, message);
    queue.offer(key);
}

public Message dequeue() throws InterruptedException {
    long updateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time = updateTime - lastUpdate;
    lastUpdate = updateTime;
    if (time > count)
        count = 0;
    else
        count -= time;
    if (count > 1000)
        Thread.sleep(1);
    count++;
    while(true) {
       String key = queue.take();
       Message msg = map.remove(key);
       if (msg != null)
           return msg;
       // if the msg is null, we have already sent the latest update for that key
    }
 }
```

This will give you an update rate of 1000 per second and always give you the latest update for any key.

Comment: I have `message` which I process but what is `key`? How I generate keys from (currentTime(), message) pair?

Comment: @gavenkoa The key identifies which messages can be drops. i.e. any message for the same key replaces a previous message for that key.  By dropping such messages as one replaces an older one, you can cut the actual rate of messages.  If you make all the keys different, you gain nothing.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to implement this would be to check the following whenever a new enqueue / add operation is requested:

> 1. Check whether the queue is full
> 2. Check whether the time since last enqueue operation is > 1/1000 seconds. 
>      2a) You can actually modify point 2 above by keeping a time
>      stamp of 1000 latest enqueue operations. Whenever an enqueue operation is requested, check the time since the first operation that was made in this queue. 
>      If it is more than 1 second, then pop out that operation from the time stamp queue and add this
>      one.

Comment: `keeping a time stamp of 1000 latest enqueue operations` what if this count too large? iterate over 1e+6 elements to keep quota precision - too cost operation...

Comment: @gavenkoa You need to keep a queue. By default the queue will always be sorted wrt time-stamps. Pushing and popping from a queue is O(1) operation. However, yes you will incur cost in terms of O(N) memory.